# Play Integrity Token Request , frequent First Time Failure

Tags: android

My application implements the Google Play Integrity API and is designed perform an Integrity check when it receives a Firebase message. The integrity check must pass before the main functionally of the application can continue

Frequently, > 50% of the time if the application has not been used for some extended amount of time  ( > 2 hours ), the first attempt to perform the integrity check fails. The application is unable to generate a new Integrity token, this is reported in the log and via a mechanism where my application send a error status to my backend server.

If a new firebase message is sent immediately or within a few minutes , the token request works and my application continues with its standard operation. Integrity check then works at normal until the application is not used , often failing again the next morning.

The exception seen below is thrown by integrityManager.requestIntegrityToken

How the application calls the IntegrityManager

```
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

// Extract nonce from payload. 

CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture = PlayIntegrityCheck.getInstance().
           getTokenWithExponentialBackoff(nonce);

}


    public CompletableFuture<String> getTokenWithExponentialBackoff(String nonce) {

        CompletableFuture<String> future = new CompletableFuture<>();

        IntegrityManager integrityManager = IntegrityManagerFactory.create(getAppContext());
        retryRequest(nonce, maxRetryAttempts, future, integrityManager);

        return future;
    }


   private void retryRequest(String nonce, int remainingAttempts, CompletableFuture<String> future, IntegrityManager integrityManager) {
        if (remainingAttempts <= 0) {
            future.completeExceptionally(new RuntimeException("Max retry attempts reached"));
            return;
        }

        if (maxRetryAttempts - remainingAttempts > 0) {
            long backoffMillis = initialBackoffMillis * (1L << (remainingAttempts - 1));
            sleepFor(backoffMillis);
        }


        integrityManager
                .requestIntegrityToken(IntegrityTokenRequest.builder().setNonce(nonce).build())
                .addOnSuccessListener(tokenResponse -> {
                    future.complete(tokenResponse.token());
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> retryRequest(nonce, remainingAttempts - 1, future, integrityManager));
    }
```

- This is not a network issue, the failure occurs on different devices and on different networks. All exhibit the same failure pattern
- Occurs when the application is in foreground & background
- As directed by the API docs the application implements an exponential backoff for making repeat attempts.
- This is a classic API request, API warm up is not required

Logs show the follow exception , but this does not tell me why the  token request fails

````
12:46:15.582 Finsky                             E  [294] rdg.a(11): requestIntegrityToken() 
                                                   com.google.android.finsky.integrityservice.IntegrityException
                                                    at rdg.c(PG:499)
                                                    at rdg.b(PG:1)
                                                    at alvd.dispatchTransaction(PG:86)
                                                    at ior.onTransact(PG:13)
                                                    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1321)
                                                    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1280)```
````